# What could be the cause of very slow socket reads?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, blocking

I am using blocking TCP sockets for my client and server. Whenever I read, I first check whether data is available on the stream using `select`.  I always read and write 40 bytes at a time. While most reads take few milliseconds or less, some just take more than half a second. That after I know that there is data available on the socket.

I am also using `TCP_NODELAY`

What could be causing it ?

**EDIT 2**

I analyzed the timestamp for each packet sent and received and saw that this delay happens only when client tries to read the object before the next object is written by the server. For instance, the server wrote object number x and after that the client tried to read object x, before the server was able to begin writing  object number x+1. This makes me suspect that some kind of coalescing is taking place on the server side.

**EDIT**

The server is listening on 3 different ports. The client connects one by one to each of these ports.

There are three connections : One that sends some data frequently from the server to the client. A second one that only sends data from the client to the server. And a third one that is used very rarely to send single byte of data. I am facing the problem with the first connection. I am checking using `select()` that data is available on that connection and then when I timestamp the 40 byte read, I find that about half a second was taken for that read.

Any pointers as to how to profile this would be very helpful

using gcc on linux.

rdrr_server_start(void)
{
  int rr_sd;
  int input_sd;
  int ack_sd;
  int fp_sd;

startTcpServer(&rr_sd, remote_rr_port);
  startTcpServer(&input_sd, remote_input_port);
  startTcpServer(&ack_sd, remote_ack_port);
  startTcpServer(&fp_sd, remote_fp_port);

connFD_rr = getTcpConnection(rr_sd);
  connFD_input = getTcpConnection(input_sd);
  connFD_ack= getTcpConnection(ack_sd);
  connFD_fp=getTcpConnection(fp_sd);
}

static int getTcpConnection(int sd)
{
  socklen_t l en;
  struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
  len = sizeof(clientAddress);
  int connFD = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddress, &len);
  nodelay(connFD);
  fflush(stdout);
  return connFD;
}

static void
startTcpServer(int *sd, const int port)
{
  *sd= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  ASSERT(*sd>0);

// Set socket option so that port can be reused
  int enable = 1;
  setsockopt(*sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int));

struct sockaddr_in a;
  memset(&a,0,sizeof(a));
  a.sin_family = AF_INET;
  a.sin_port = port;
  a.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  int bindResult = bind(*sd, (struct sockaddr *) &a, sizeof(a));
  ASSERT(bindResult ==0);
  listen(*sd,2);
}
static void nodelay(int fd) {
  int flag=1;
  ASSERT(setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &flag, sizeof flag)==0);
}

startTcpClient() {
  connFD_rr = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  connFD_input = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  connFD_ack = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  connFD_fp= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

struct sockaddr_in a;
  memset(&a,0,sizeof(a));
  a.sin_family = AF_INET;
  a.sin_port = remote_rr_port;
  a.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(remote_server_ip);

int CONNECT_TO_SERVER= connect(connFD_rr,  &a, sizeof(a));
  ASSERT(CONNECT_TO_SERVER==0) ;

a.sin_port = remote_input_port;
  CONNECT_TO_SERVER= connect(connFD_input,  &a, sizeof(a));
  ASSERT(CONNECT_TO_SERVER==0) ;

a.sin_port = remote_ack_port;
  CONNECT_TO_SERVER= connect(connFD_ack,  &a, sizeof(a));
  ASSERT(CONNECT_TO_SERVER==0) ;

a.sin_port = remote_fp_port;
  CONNECT_TO_SERVER= connect(connFD_fp,  &a, sizeof(a));
  ASSERT(CONNECT_TO_SERVER==0) ;

nodelay(connFD_rr);
  nodelay(connFD_input);
  nodelay(connFD_ack);
  nodelay(connFD_fp);
}

Comment: I got a feeling that this problem is hardware related...

Comment: **One that sends some data frequently from the server to the client**, what size we are talking about?

Comment: Maybe TCP_NODELAY (disabling Nagle) is a bad choice, resulting in many short segments to be sent, resulting in multiple round-trips per "logical" packet. Plus a lot of systemcalls at the side of the application program.

Comment: @wildplasser Can that happen even if I `write()` the complete "logical" packet all at once? I cannot allow any latency between the client and the server and thats why I have disable Nagle

Comment: @tuxuday exactly 40 bytes data, 2-5 times per 10 miliseconds

Comment: Does the sender use multiple write()s to send one "logical" packet ? Maybe you should consider writev() and/or re-enable Nagle. (or maybe even TCP_CORK)

Comment: If you can deal with packet loss, UDP would also be an option. for reference: http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.11.shtml (and next pages, too) BTW: if you can not stand (variations in) latency, you should not use a network.

Comment: also, can you launch [**ethereal**](http://www.ethereal.com/download.html) and observe how packets are sent over?

Comment: use [**wireshark**](http://www.wireshark.org/) instead of **ethereal**

Comment: There can be no network delay as I am keeping both the client and server on the same machine. I cannot deal with packet loss.

Comment: @tuxuday The code is a part of a feature I am implementing for qemu-kvm and is distributed over too many files too be able to post any snippet

Comment: can you use any of packet analyzers in that box? **wireshark**

Comment: If it is on the same machine you could also choose (named) pipes as an interface, avoiding the TCP/IP layers. There also might be some I/O scheduling involved.

Comment: @wilplasser I am just testing this on same machine currently. Eventually it will be run on two different machines

Answer (score 1):

I would be suspicious of the this line of code:

```
ASSERT(setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &flag, sizeof flag)==0);
```

If you are running a release build, then ASSERT is mostly likely defined to nothing, so the call would not actually be made.  The setsockopt call should not be in the ASSERT statement. Instead, the return value (in a variable) should be verified in the assert statement.  [Asserts with side effects](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP31-C.+Avoid+side+effects+in+assertions) are generally a bad thing.  So even if this is not the problem, it should probably be changed.

Comment: Oh I haven't actually shown the ASSERT part that is defined in my code. It works fine.

Comment: This code is still counter-idiomatic; putting code with side effects as an argument of a macro named `ASSERT` is very confusing to readers who are likely to assume it doesn't run on non-debug builds.

Comment: @AnkurVj:  Even if you think it is fine, you might try removing the call from the assert.  Not that I am doubting your abilities, but it is rare that anyone writes an ASSERT macro correctly the first time.

Comment: Oh okay, perhaps its a bad idea to use macros in code snippets that I haven't shown what they expand to

Answer (score 0):

One client and multiple connections?

some of socket functions might be blocking your execution (i.e. waiting for result of functions). I would suggest opening a new thread (on server side) for each connection so they won't interfere with each other...

but I'm shooting in the dark; you'll need to send some additional info...

Comment: I have added some detail in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if your problem lies there, but you should probably rearrange your startTcpServer/getTcpConnection functions. startTcpServer features a call to listen() which will block program execution until new connection is made. After that you should accept new connection and move on, but you have yet another call to startTcpServer => another listen... (all on the same thread)

So instead accepting incoming connection, your socket listens (but in another function)...

Perhaps rearrange them like:

startTcpServer();
getTcpConnection();

startTcpServer();
getTcpConnection();

?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is still confusing i.e. "multiple tcp connections with only one client". Obviously you have a single server listening on one port. Now if you have multiple connections this means there is more than one client connecting to the server each connected on a different tcp client port. Now server runs select and responds to whichever client has data (meaning client sent some data on his socket). Now if two clients send data simultaneously, server can only process them sequentially. So second client won't get processed until server is done processing with first.

Select only allows server to monitor more than one descriptors (sockets) and process which ever has data available. It is not like that it does processing in parallel. You need multiple threads or processes for that.

Comment: No actually, the server accepted connections on three different ports from the same client. Ideally each connection should be completely isolated from the other.

Comment: Can you please paste your code which shows creation of three different server sockets and it's passing to select?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is something related to the `timeout` argument.

What do you set for `timeout` argument of `select` call?

Try to change the timeout argument to a bigger one and observe the latency. Sometimes too small timeout and very often system calls can actually kill throughput . Maybe you can achieve better results if you assume a little bigger latency, that is realizable.

I suspect timeout or some code bug.

Comment: Could you paste the code with call to `select` and `read` from socket after `select` returns ?

Comment: @AnkurVj Why? That's an amazingly short timeout. Maybe you are starving yourself of the processor. A select() timeout is normally a couple of seconds at least. What do you have to do that has to be done every 30ms?

Comment: @EJP I have to call a function once after that timeout before going ahead and blocking on the read. I dont do this repeatedly. Just once. And then I do a blocking read

Comment: @AnkurVj so maybe you should use a short timeout for the first call to `select`, and longer timeouts in next calls. Using very short polls with TCP_NODELAY could be very inefficient. Probably normal (no real time) OS-es are not optimized for such use cases.

Comment: Inefficient as in more bandwidth usage ? The problem for me is perhaps not efficiency, but latency. I cannot have the client wait for data from the server even though the server has already done 'write()'. It has to be instantly available to the client

Comment: When you set TCP_NODELAY operating system have no chance to group message bytes in bigger packets, so it must send small packets immediately. This is inefficient. Imagine you have to deliver some sand to the different part of your town. You load some sand to the truck but you decide to drive before your truck is far to be full. You wait shorter for first delivery, but you must go many times. So all the work takes longer. (Systems are optimized for packets with about 1500 bytes and more)

Comment: If this is some kind of an error, could you show us the actual call to POSIX `select` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `TCP_CORK` (CORK'ed mode) with kernel extensions `GRO`, `GSO` and `TSO` disabled by `ethtool`:

- sending inside `TCP_CORK` flagged session will ensure that the data will not be sent in partial segment
- disabling `generic-segmentation-offload`, `generic-receive-offload` and `tcp-segmentation-offload` will ensure that kernel will not introduce artificial delays to collect additional tcp segments before moving data to/from userspace